# Theoretically can the Ackermann function be optimized?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, ackermann

I am wondering if there can be a version of Ackermann function with better time complexity than the standard variation.

This is not a homework and I am just curious. I know the Ackermann function doesn't have any practical use besides as a performance benchmark, because of the deep recursion. I know the numbers grow very large very quickly, and I am not interested in computing it.

Even though I use Python 3 and the integers won't overflow, I do have finite time, but I have implemented a version of it myself according to the definition found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function), and computed the output for extremely small values, just to make sure the output is correct.

[image]

```
def A(m, n):
    if not m:
        return n + 1
    return A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1)) if n else A(m - 1, 1)
```

The above code is a direct translation of the image, and is extremely slow, I don't know how it can be optimized, is it impossible to optimize it?

One thing I can think of is to memoize it, but the recursion runs backwards, each time the function is recursively called the arguments were not encountered before, each successive function call the arguments decrease rather than increase, therefore each return value of the function needs to be calculated, memoization doesn't help when you call the function with different arguments the first time.

Memoization can only help if you call it with the same arguments again, it won't compute the results and will retrieve cached result instead, but if you call the function with any input with (m, n) >= (4, 2) it will crash the interpreter regardless.

I also implemented another version according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20411205/16383578):

```
def ack(x, y):
    for i in range(x, 0, -1):
        y = ack(i, y - 1) if y else 1
    return y + 1
```

But it is actually slower:

```
In [2]: %timeit A(3, 4)
1.3 ms ± 9.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit ack(3, 4)
2 ms ± 59.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Theoretically can Ackermann function be optimized? If not, can it be definitely proven that its time complexity cannot decrease?

---

I have just tested `A(3, 9)` and `A(4, 1)` will crash the interpreter, and the performance of the two functions for `A(3, 8)`:

```
In [2]: %timeit A(3, 8)
432 ms ± 4.63 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [3]: %timeit ack(3, 8)
588 ms ± 10.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

I did some more experiments:

```
from collections import Counter
from functools import cache

c = Counter()
def A1(m, n):
    c[(m, n)] += 1
    if not m:
        return n + 1
    return A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1)) if n else A(m - 1, 1)

def test(m, n):
    c.clear()
    A1(m, n)
    return c
```

The arguments indeed repeat.

But surprisingly caching doesn't help at all:

```
In [9]: %timeit Ackermann = cache(A); Ackermann(3, 4)
1.3 ms ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Caching only helps when the function is called with the same arguments again, as explained:

```
In [14]: %timeit Ackermann(3, 2)
101 ns ± 0.47 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000,000 loops each)
```

I have tested it with different arguments numerous times, and it always gives the same efficiency boost (which is none).

Comment: This question might be more suitable for https://cs.stackexchange.com/ or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ Guessing by a quick Google Scholar search the implementation of the Ackermann function can be optimized, e.g. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397588900461 (1988) or https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/966049.777398 (2003)

Comment: I don't think there's much you can do outside of cheating and simply using a hardcoded lookup table for small values of m and n and erroring for larger values.

Comment: According to the Wikipedia page that you mentioned, you cannot avoid a huge time complexity. However, depending of the algorithm, you may have or not a huge space complexity. And a huge space complexity may crash your program.

Comment: Memoization totally helps time complexity. Just put a simple `print(m, n)` a the beginning and call `A(3, 2)`. You will see repeated values over and over. E.g. A(1, 5) is called 16 times. Caching will most definitely make it faster.

Comment: [This earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70601131/understanding-grossman-zeitmans-algorithm-for-computing-the-ackermann-functio/70656571#70656571) explores a fast iterative algorithm for computing Ackermann values. I haven’t benchmarked it but perhaps it fits your needs? (It’s also asymptotically faster than the naive recursion.)

Comment: You can look up the recursive definition of addition or multiplication - while interesting, it is extremely inefficient to use them directly to compute addition and multiplication of anything but small numbers. We have very efficient algorithms to sum and multiply. So you should not in general expect a recursive definition to necessarily be efficient, and most often it won't be.

Comment: One thing to note is that the running time can at best be linear in the size (i.e. the number of digits) of the output, at least if you output all the digits. This provides a lower bound on how fast the algorithm can be.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Solution

I recently wrote a bunch of solutions based on the same paper that templatetypedef mentioned. Many use generators, one for each m-value, yielding the values for n=0, n=1, n=2, etc. This one might be my favorite:

```
def A_Stefan_generator_stack3(m, n):
    def a(m):
        if not m:
            yield from count(1)
        x = 1
        for i, ai in enumerate(a(m-1)):
            if i == x:
                x = ai
                yield x
    return next(islice(a(m), n, None))
```

### Explanation

Consider the generator `a(m)`. It yields A(m,0), A(m,1), A(m,2), etc. The definition of A(m,n) uses A(m-1, A(m, n-1)). So `a(m)` at its index n yields A(m,n), computed like this:

- A(m,n-1) gets yielded by the  `a(m)` generator itself at index n-1. Which is just the previous value (x) yielded by this generator.
- A(m-1, A(m, n-1)) = A(m-1, x) gets yielded by the `a(m-1)` generator at index x. So the `a(m)` generator iterates over the `a(m-1)` generator and grabs the value at index i == x.

### Benchmark

Here are times for computing all A(m,n) for m≤3 and n≤17, also including templatetypedef's solution:

```
 1325 ms  A_Stefan_row_class
 1228 ms  A_Stefan_row_lists
  544 ms  A_Stefan_generators
 1363 ms  A_Stefan_paper
  459 ms  A_Stefan_generators_2
  866 ms  A_Stefan_m_recursion
  704 ms  A_Stefan_function_stack
  468 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack
  945 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack2
  582 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack3
  467 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack4
 1652 ms  A_templatetypedef
```

Note: Even faster (*much* faster) solutions using math insights/formulas are possible, see [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559257/theoretically-can-the-ackermann-function-be-optimized/76561503#comment134988343_76561010) and [pts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76562536/1672429). I intentionally didn't do that, as I was interested in *coding* techniques, for avoiding deep recursion and avoiding *re*-calculation. I got the impression that that's also what the question/OP wanted, and they [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76559257/theoretically-can-the-ackermann-function-be-optimized/76561503#comment134989599_76561954) that now (under a deleted answer, visible if you have enough reputation).

### Code

```
def A_Stefan_row_class(m, n):
    class A0:
        def __getitem__(self, n):
            return n + 1
    class A:
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a
            self.n = 0
            self.value = a[1]
        def __getitem__(self, n):
            while self.n < n:
                self.value = self.a[self.value]
                self.n += 1
            return self.value
    a = A0()
    for _ in range(m):
        a = A(a)
    return a[n]


from collections import defaultdict

def A_Stefan_row_lists(m, n):
    memo = defaultdict(list)
    def a(m, n):
        if not m:
            return n + 1
        if m not in memo:
            memo[m] = [a(m-1, 1)]
        Am = memo[m]
        while len(Am) <= n:
            Am.append(a(m-1, Am[-1]))
        return Am[n]
    return a(m, n)


from itertools import count

def A_Stefan_generators(m, n):
    a = count(1)
    def up(a, x=1):
        for i, ai in enumerate(a):
            if i == x:
                x = ai
                yield x
    for _ in range(m):
        a = up(a)
    return next(up(a, n))


def A_Stefan_paper(m, n):
    next = [0] * (m + 1)
    goal = [1] * m + [-1]
    while True:
        value = next[0] + 1
        transferring = True
        i = 0
        while transferring:
            if next[i] == goal[i]:
                goal[i] = value
            else:
                transferring = False
            next[i] += 1
            i += 1
        if next[m] == n + 1:
            return value


def A_Stefan_generators_2(m, n):
    def a0():
        n = yield
        while True:
            n = yield n + 1
    def up(a):
        next(a)
        a = a.send
        i, x = -1, 1
        n = yield
        while True:
            while i < n:
                x = a(x)
                i += 1
            n = yield x
    a = a0()
    for _ in range(m):
        a = up(a)
    next(a)
    return a.send(n)


def A_Stefan_m_recursion(m, n):
    ix = [None] + [(-1, 1)] * m
    def a(m, n):
        if not m:
            return n + 1
        i, x = ix[m]
        while i < n:
            x = a(m-1, x)
            i += 1
        ix[m] = i, x
        return x
    return a(m, n)


def A_Stefan_function_stack(m, n):
    def a(n):
        return n + 1
    for _ in range(m):
        def a(n, a=a, ix=[-1, 1]):
            i, x = ix
            while i < n:
                x = a(x)
                i += 1
            ix[:] = i, x
            return x
    return a(n)


from itertools import count, islice

def A_Stefan_generator_stack(m, n):
    a = count(1)
    for _ in range(m):
        a = (
            x
            for a, x in [(a, 1)]
            for i, ai in enumerate(a)
            if i == x
            for x in [ai]
        )
    return next(islice(a, n, None))


from itertools import count, islice

def A_Stefan_generator_stack2(m, n):
    a = count(1)
    def up(a):
        i, x = 0, 1
        while True:
            i, x = x+1, next(islice(a, x-i, None))
            yield x
    for _ in range(m):
        a = up(a)
    return next(islice(a, n, None))


def A_Stefan_generator_stack3(m, n):
    def a(m):
        if not m:
            yield from count(1)
        x = 1
        for i, ai in enumerate(a(m-1)):
            if i == x:
                x = ai
                yield x
    return next(islice(a(m), n, None))


def A_Stefan_generator_stack4(m, n):
    def a(m):
        if not m:
            return count(1)
        return (
            x
            for x in [1]
            for i, ai in enumerate(a(m-1))
            if i == x
            for x in [ai]
        )
    return next(islice(a(m), n, None))


def A_templatetypedef(i, n):
    positions = [-1] * (i + 1)
    values = [0] + [1] * i
    
    while positions[i] != n:       
        values[0]    += 1
        positions[0] += 1
            
        j = 1
        while j <= i and positions[j - 1] == values[j]:
            values[j] = values[j - 1]
            positions[j] += 1
            j += 1

    return values[i]


funcs = [
    A_Stefan_row_class,
    A_Stefan_row_lists,
    A_Stefan_generators,
    A_Stefan_paper,
    A_Stefan_generators_2,
    A_Stefan_m_recursion,
    A_Stefan_function_stack,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack2,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack3,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack4,
    A_templatetypedef,
]

N = 18
args = (
    [(0, n) for n in range(N)] +
    [(1, n) for n in range(N)] +
    [(2, n) for n in range(N)] +
    [(3, n) for n in range(N)]
)

from time import time

def print(*args, print=print, file=open('out.txt', 'w')):
    print(*args)
    print(*args, file=file, flush=True)
    
expect = none = object()
for _ in range(3):
  for f in funcs:
    t = time()
    result = [f(m, n) for m, n in args]
    # print(f'{(time()-t) * 1e3 :5.1f} ms ', f.__name__)
    print(f'{(time()-t) * 1e3 :5.0f} ms ', f.__name__)
    if expect is none:
        expect = result
    elif result != expect:
        raise Exception(f'{f.__name__} failed')
    del result
  print()
```

Comment: A thought on how to improve this: we know that A(1, n) = 2n + 3 for all n. Perhaps you can eliminate the last two levels of the recursion by directly returning 2n+3 whenever A(1, n) is requested?

Comment: @templatetypedef Well, yes, and there are similar formulas for m=2 and m=3, and a simple faster calculation for m=4. So we could optimize a few more levels with that. I personally wasn't interested in that *math* solution. I was actually preparing a question+answer about this myself, ruling out such math solutions in the question. It was going to be about *coding* techniques, about avoiding deep recursion and avoiding recalculation. Skipping values with math insights was going to be ruled out. Somehow I thought this question also wanted that, but I see now that I misread it. Oh well :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef Hmm, that said, while the formulas for small m are boring, the ones for larger m, using arrow notation, might be interesting. They're shown in the [table of values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Table_of_values) on Wikipedia. There's even A(m,n) = (2 → (n+3) → (m-2)) - 3, but I don't remember what the arrow notation means. Might be fun to implement that.

Comment: Also… any idea why my implementation is so slow? I’m surprised that it was the worst of the bunch. :-)

Comment: @templatetypedef: Your implementation is slow because you did memoization (`cache(...)`) incorrectly, see Kelly Bundy's answer. Other reasons for the slowness can be that other implementations are extremely smart.

Comment: @templatetypedef Some things that I *think* play a role, especially compared to my generators: Let's think of it as a 2D matrix where A(m,n) is in row m and column n. You have one big "piece of code" that does *everything*. My generators are each responsible for just one row. That has advantages: (1) I let Python handle the coordination between the rows, i.e., which row to advance next and the transfer of values between rows. You do that yourself instead.

Comment: @templatetypedef (continuing) (2) Your values are all in lists. My generators each have their own values in simple variables. Accessing list elements is slower. (3) Most of the action is in the top two rows, and my top row is fast. Especially in my `stack4` solution, where it's just `itertools.count(1)`, not a Python generator but a C iterator.

Comment: @templatetypedef (continuing) All that said, I also have non-generator solutions, and they're not much faster than yours. Especially my `A_Stefan_paper` solution, which is a direct translation from the paper's pseudo code to Python (and renamed two variables) and very similar to yours. It's still a bit faster than yours, I guess my implementation just does fewer operations or fewer list accesses per "step" than yours. We could count those, but I dont find it interesting enough, doesn't seem like it would lead to some great insight.

Comment: @pts I think you confused templatetypedef with the OP?

Comment: @templatetypedef: CPython interpreter overhead is huge if you use the standard CPython implementation.  In C++ with gmplib for arbitrary-precision bigints, this should run significantly faster if you can manage the integer lengths so you're not grinding through tons of high zeros.  (CPython uses 30-bit chunks for big integers even on 64-bit machines, without any hand-written asm, vs. gmplib using native register size, e.g. 64-bit chunks, so you can have more efficient bigint as well as minimal overhead from looping.)

Answer (score 19):

You are asking these two questions in your text:

> Theoretically can Ackermann function be optimized?

Sure, you can implement it naively, and then optimize that in technical ways (e.g. memoization, or storing intermediate values, and so on). But I think this is not the actual question you are asking.

> If not, can it be definitely proven that its time complexity cannot decrease?

Optimization has nothing to do with time complexity. The "O" notation abstracts away from constant multiplicative factors. You can have two algorithms where the one calculates the Ackermann function in 1 millionth of the time or space than the other, but they would still have the same O complexity.

To quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function),

> the Ackermann function, named after Wilhelm Ackermann, is one of the simplest[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) and earliest-discovered examples of a total computable function that is not primitive recursive.

The function is [not primitive recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Not_primitive_recursive), and furthermore, it

> grows faster than any primitive recursive function.

"Primitive recursive" means that you can implement the algorithm with loops where the bound is known beforehand; i.e. you do not need a possible infinitely repeating `while` loop. This is, granted, a bit of an abstract concept, and to quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_recursive_function) again:

> The importance of primitive recursive functions lies in the fact that most computable functions that are studied in number theory (and more generally in mathematics) are primitive recursive.

And yes, it has been [proven](https://planetmath.org/ackermannfunctionisnotprimitiverecursive) that Ackermann is not primitive recursive. Discovering that it is actually not so would probably not make you any money, but certainly put your name on a pedestal, in the Theoretical Computer Science community.

You cannot optimize this kind of complexity away - consider your program just being a different format of writing a proof that the Ackerman is, indeed, primitive recursive; you'd just have to convert it back into mathematical/logical terms, and voila. The fact that this has not happened over the many years, together with the existence of "proof positive" like the one linked tells you that it is, in fact, behaving as advertised.

NB: finally, all of this has also to be seen in the light of the Ackerman function having likely been *designed* to have this property - as that Wikipedia page mentions, before it was discovered or created, some people thought that *all* computable functions were primitive recursive. While I don't know what drove Mr. Ackerman to do this back in the 1920's, the Ackerman function is now verily a corner-stone of complexity theory in Theoretical Computer Science; a very fascinating story.

Comment: The primitive recursive property means that if you need a loop you are able to know  in advance how many iterations are needed. In general this is not possible, the condition to exit the loop might only be computed while performing the loop.

Comment: @mvw, yes; the answer is talking about a "function" (something with input and output, more in a mathematical sense) obviously in the real world there are many while loops that have no bound - for example the event loop in a GUI app and such, or a network app waiting for incoming requests. But for "functions" (in a mathematical/logical sense) the vast majority is primitive recursive. See the linked page for examples.

Comment: A naive recursive Fibonacci runs in `O(Fib(n))`.  A simple iterative Fibonacci runs in `O(n)`, same for memoizing a recursive Fibonacci.  Huge improvements in the complexity class are possible with algorithmic optimizations, or just memoization of repeatedly-calculated subproblems.  Of course the best you can possibly do for Ackermann is provably not that fast by design, but it can be a different O(f(n)) complexity class than the most naive implementation.

Comment: `strlen` is a good example of a loop whose trip-count isn't known in advance, like @mvw described.  (Fun fact, compilers like GCC and clang can't auto-vectorize such loops.)  Implicit-length data structures like C strings and linked lists are not rare in computer programs, although most programs could use explicit-length things instead and still compute the same thing.  And could do stuff like always loop over the whole array instead of an early-exit from a search loop, if that's necessary to stay in the realm of primitive-recursive?

Comment: @petercordes, `strlen` can be capped by the maximum possible string length in a given system - trivially by taking the maximum amount of RAM available in the current machine as upper limit of the `for`loop. Totally impractical, but in the sense of TCS it's perfectly fine...

Comment: *"You cannot optimize this kind of complexity away"* - What does optimizing it "away" mean, and who asked for that? The question asks about *decreasing* the time complexity. Are you saying their original implementation has a certain complexity (which one? can you give the big-O notation?) and you can't get away from that, i.e., no optimization is possible that improves it by more than a constant factor?

Answer (score 15):

v0 is pretty much your code:

```
def ack(m, n):
  if m == 0: return n + 1
  return ack(m - 1, 1) if n == 0 else ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))
```

This calculates ack(3, 9) in 2.49s. ack() is called 11164370 times. Surely we can cache the values already calculated saving tonns of calls to the function.

v1 uses a dict for a cache and only calculates if the result is not in the cache:

```
c = {}

def ack(m, n):
  global c

  if "{}-{}".format(m, n) in c: return c["{}-{}".format(m, n)]
  else:
    if m == 0: ret = n + 1
    else: ret = ack(m - 1, 1) if n == 0 else ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))

    c["{}-{}".format(m, n)] = ret
    return ret
```

This calculates ack(3, 9) in 0.03s and with that ack(3, 9) is no longer suitable for measuring execution time. This time ack() is called 12294 times, the saving is enormous. But we can do it better. From now on we use ack(3, 13) that currently runs for 0.23s.

v2 only cares for caching where m > 0, since the case of m == 0 is trivial. With that space complexity is somewhat reduced:

```
c = {}

def ack(m, n):
  global c

  if m == 0: return n + 1
  else:
    if "{}-{}".format(m, n) in c: return c["{}-{}".format(m, n)]
    else: ret = ack(m - 1, 1) if n == 0 else ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))

    c["{}-{}".format(m, n)] = ret
    return ret
```

This finishes ack(3, 13) in 0.18s. But we can to even better.

v3 saves a bit of time by calculating the key in the cache only once per iteration:

```
c = {}

def ack(m, n):
  global c

  if m == 0: return n + 1
  else:
    key = "{}-{}".format(m, n)
    if key in c: return c[key]
    else: ret = ack(m - 1, 1) if n == 0 else ack(m - 1, ack(m, n - 1))

    c[key] = ret
    return ret
```

This time it runs for 0.14s. I surely can't do much more to it around midnight but I will think about it some more. Ez jó mulatság, férfi munka volt - for those who know what that means.

Comment: You can use tuples as dictionary keys.

Comment: Sure, I don't really program in Python, only for DIY purposes like this. I'm sure the pros can take it a bit further. I might have another look at it tomorrow. The problem is that running it guts out my laptop. ack(3, 14) explodes even with max recursion set to 200000, yet it finishes in 0.14s :D

Answer (score 12):

Here’s my stab at a Python implementation of the [Grossman-Zeitman algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70601131/501557), which iteratively computes A(i, n) in O(A(i, n)) time. For a description of how this algorithm works, check the linked question.

```py
def ackermann(i, n):
    positions = [-1] * (i + 1)
    values = [0] + [1] * i
    
    while positions[i] != n:       
        values[0]    += 1
        positions[0] += 1
            
        j = 1
        while j <= i and positions[j - 1] == values[j]:
            values[j] = values[j - 1]
            positions[j] += 1
            j += 1

    return values[i]
```

Given that the inner loop is very tight and there’s no recursion, I suspect this will likely outperform the basic recursive solution you initially posted. However, I haven’t correctness- or time-tested this implementation; it’s based on the Java code I wrote in the linked question.

Comment: `O(A(i, n))` on a machine with O(1) operation cost not just for operands a fixed multiple of the input (n), but the output (A(i, n)). *Not* [RAM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_machine).

Comment: I suspect (but haven’t worked out the full argument) that this is actually O(A(i, n)) even on a RAM machine. Each increment operation is amortized O(1) even if the integers in question use a huge number of bits, and the cost of copying a large number can be reduced by just storing a pointer to the numbers in question. Though perhaps there’s a small technical detail I’m missing?

Comment: I expect the comparison `positions[j - 1] == values[j]` to take ~ log(A(i-1, n)) time. In case of equality; what about inequality? Amortised constant, I guess.

Answer (score 11):

> But surprisingly caching doesn't help at all:
>
> ```
> In [9]: %timeit Ackermann = cache(A); Ackermann(3, 4)
> 1.3 ms ± 10.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
> ```

That's because you did that wrong. Only your `Ackermann` is memoized, not your `A`. And the recursive calls all go to `A`.

Times for m,n = 3,8, including a properly memoized version `B`:

```
440.30 ms  A(m, n)
431.11 ms  Ackermann = cache(A); Ackermann(m, n)
  1.74 ms  B.cache_clear(); B(m, n)
```

About `B`:

- Print `B.cache_info())` afterwards to see how well the cache did: `CacheInfo(hits=1029, misses=5119, maxsize=None, currsize=5119)`. So `B` had 5,119 "real" calls (where it had to do work) and 1,029 calls that were answered from cache. Without the memoization, it gets called 2,785,999 times.
- For m,n = 3,12 it takes ~32 ms.
- For m,n = 3,13 it crashes due to the deep recursion.

Code:

```
from timeit import repeat
import sys

sys.setrecursionlimit(999999)

setup = '''
from functools import cache

def A(m, n):
    if not m:
        return n + 1
    return A(m - 1, A(m, n - 1)) if n else A(m - 1, 1)

@cache
def B(m, n):
    if not m:
        return n + 1
    return B(m - 1, B(m, n - 1)) if n else B(m - 1, 1)

m, n = 3, 8
'''

codes = [
    'A(m, n)',
    'Ackermann = cache(A); Ackermann(m, n)',
    'B.cache_clear(); B(m, n)',
]

for code in codes:
    t = min(repeat(code, setup, number=1))
    print(f'{t*1e3:6.2f} ms ', code)
```

Answer (score 9):

**TL;DR** The Ackermann function grows so rapidly that for (m >= 4 and n >= 3) the result won't fit to RAM. For smaller values of m or n, it's very easy to compute the values directly (without recursion) and quickly.

I know that this answer doesn't help optimizing recursive function calls, nevertheless it provides a fast solution (with analysis) for computing values of the Ackermann function on real, contemporary computers, and it provides a direct answer to the first paragraph of the question.

We want to store the result in an unsigned binary big integer variable on a
computer. To store the value 2 ** b, we need (b + 1) bits of data, and (c1 + c2 * ceil(log2(b))) bits of header for storing the length b itself. (c1 is a
nonnegative integer, c2 is a positive integer.) Thus we need more than b
bits of RAM to store 2 ** b.

Computers with huge amounts of RAM:

- In 2023 consumer-grade PCs have up to 128 GiB of RAM, and there are commercially
  available servers with 2 TiB of RAM
  (https://ramforyou.com/is-it-possible-for-a-computer-have-1tb-ram).
- In 2020, a single-rack server with 6 TiB of RAM was built
  (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHAfTty9UWY).
- In 2017, a large server with 160 TiB of RAM was constructed
  (https://www.forbes.com/sites/aarontilley/2017/05/16/hpe-160-terabytes-memory/).
- So we can say that in 2023 it's not feasible to build a computer with 1
  PiB == 1024 TiB of RAM, and 1 EiB == 1024 PiB == 1048576 TiB == (2 ** 63)
  bits is completely impossible in 2023 and the near future.
- The current estimate for the number of atoms in the universe is 10 ** 82
  == 10 * 10 ** 81 < 16 * 2 ** 270 < 2 ** 274.
- Let's imagine the biggest computer. Even if there are many more atoms, say
  2 ** 300, and we can use all of them in a single computer, and we can
  store 1 EiB of data in a single atom, thus we have 2 ** 363 bits of
  memory; that's still too small to store the *Big* value 2 ** (2 ** 363).

Let's see which of Knuth's up-arrow notation
(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation) values are less
than *Big*:

- 2 ^ b == 2 ** b: It works for 1 <= b <= (2 ** 363 - 1).

  2 ^ (2 ** 363) == 2 ** (2 ** 363) == Big >= Big.
- 2 ^^ b: It works for 1 <= b <= 5.

  2 ^^ 1 == 2;

  2 ^^ 2 == 2 ** 2 == 4;

  2 ^^ 3 == 2 ** (2 ** 2) == 16;

  2 ^^ 4 == 2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 2)) == 65536;

  2 ^^ 5 == 2 ** (2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 2))) == 2 ** 65536 == 2 ** (2 ** 16) < Big;

  2 ^^ 6 == 2 ** (2 ** (2 ** (2 ** (2 ** 2)))) == 2 ** (2 ** 65536) >= Big.
- 2 ^^^ b: It works for 1 <= b <= 3.

  2 ^^^ 1 == 2;

  2 ^^^ 2 == 2 ^^ 2 == 4;

  2 ^^^ 3 == 2 ^^ (2 ^^ 2) == 65536;

  2 ^^^ 4 == 2 ^^ (2 ^^ (2 ^^ 2)) == 2 ^^ 65536 >= 2 ^^ 6 >= Big.
- 2 ^^^^ b: It works for 1 <= b <= 2.

  2 ^^^^ 1 == 2;

  2 ^^^^ 2 == 2 ^^^ 2 == 4;

  2 ^^^^ 3 == 2 ^^^ (2 ^^^ 2) == 2 ^^^ 4 == 2 ^^ 65536 >= 2 ^^ 6 >= Big.
- 2 ^^^^^ b and even more arrows: It works for 1 <= b <= 2. The value is at
  least 2 ^^^^ b, see there.

Thus here is how to compute the feasible values in Python:

```
def up_arrow(a, b):
  if b <= 2:
    if b < 0:
      raise ValueError
    return (1, 2, 4)[b]
  elif a == 1:
    if b >> 363:
      raise ValueError
    return 1 << b  # This may run out of memory for large b.
  elif a == 2:
    if b > 5:
      raise ValueError
    if b == 5:
      return 1 << 65536
    return (16, 65536)[b - 3]
  elif a == 3:
    if b > 3:
      raise ValueError
    return 65536
  else:
    raise ValueError
```

Given that for m >= 3, ack(m, n) == up_arrow(m - 2, n + 3) - 3
(see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function#Table_of_values),
we can compute the feasible values of the Ackermann function:

```
def ack(m, n):
  if n < 0:
    raise ValueError
  if m in (0, 1):
    return n + (m + 1)  # This may run out of memory for large n.
  elif m == 2:
    return (n << 1) + 3  # This may run out of memory for large n.
  elif m == 3:
    if n >> 360:
      raise ValueError
    return (1 << (n + 3)) - 3  # This may run out of memory for large n.
  elif m == 4:
    if n > 2:
      raise ValueError
    if n == 2:
      return (1 << 65536) - 3
    return (13, 65533)[n]
  elif m == 5:
    if n > 0:
      raise ValueError
    return 65533
  else:
    raise ValueError

print([ack(m, 0) for m in range(6)])
print([ack(m, 1) for m in range(5)])
print([ack(m, 2) for m in range(5)])
print([ack(m, 3) for m in range(4)])
print([ack(m, 4) for m in range(4)])
```

Answer (score 7):

The question has tag Python, but using `ctypes` to call C++ code is also a Python feature. It contains 3 versions (I measure time cost of `result = [ackermann(m,n) for m<=3, n <= 17]`, like in the top answer)

- **Use int64_t and recursion with memoization => 32ms**. It'll only work for small inputs (just like all the algorithms in the top answer). It's focused on optimizing recursive function.
- **Use bignum and same algorithm as above => 32ms** Since the bignum lib I used is implemented using 64 bit base type, if the result fit in small numbers it's no different from using `int64_t` directly. I added this because comments mentioned it's unfair to compare C++ `int64_t` vs Python unlimited length integer.
- **Use bignum + math formula => ~~0.14 ms** This one will also work with bigger inputs.

**Summary: > 3000x faster than top Python answer if you use math, or 13-15x faster if you don't use math.** I use this [single-header-file bignum library](https://github.com/983/Num/blob/master/num.hpp). Stackoverflow has answer length limit so I can't copy the file here.

```
// ackermann.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>
#include "num.hpp"
using namespace std;

class MyTimer {
    std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start;

public:
    void startCounter() {
        start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    }

    int64_t getCounterNs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    int64_t getCounterMs() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count();
    }

    double getCounterMsPrecise() {
        return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now() - start).count()
                / 1000000.0;
    }
};

extern "C" {
  int64_t ackermann(int64_t m, int64_t n) {
    static std::vector<int64_t> cache[4];
    // special signal to clear cache
    if (m < 0 && n < 0) {      
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cache[i].resize(0);
        cache[i].shrink_to_fit();      
      }
      return -1;
    }
    
    if (n >= cache[m].size()) {
      int cur = cache[m].size();
      cache[m].resize(n + 1);
      for (int i = cur; i < n; i++) cache[m][i] = ackermann(m, i);
    }

    if (cache[m][n]) return cache[m][n];
    if (m == 0) return cache[m][n] = n + 1;
    
    // These 3 lines are kinda cheating, since it uses math formula for special case
    // So I commented them out because the question is about optimizing recursion.
    // if (m == 1) return cache[m][n] = n + 2;
    // if (m == 2) return cache[m][n] = 2 * n + 3;
    // if (m == 3) return cache[m][n] = (1LL << (n + 3)) - 3;

    if (n == 0) return cache[m][n] = ackermann(m - 1, 1);

    return cache[m][n] = ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));        
  }

  Num ackermann_bignum_smallres(int64_t m, int64_t n) {
    static std::vector<Num> cache[4];
    // special signal to clear cache
    if (m < 0 && n < 0) {      
      for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cache[i].resize(0);
        cache[i].shrink_to_fit();      
      }
      return -1;
    }
    
    if (n >= cache[m].size()) {
      int cur = cache[m].size();
      cache[m].resize(n + 1);
      for (int i = cur; i < n; i++) cache[m][i] = ackermann(m, i);
    }

    if (cache[m][n] > 0) return cache[m][n];
    if (m == 0) return cache[m][n] = n + 1;

    if (n == 0) return cache[m][n] = ackermann(m - 1, 1);

    return cache[m][n] = ackermann(m - 1, ackermann(m, n - 1));
  }

  //-----
  Num bignum_pow(const Num& x, const Num& n) {
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    Num mid = bignum_pow(x, n / 2);
    if (n % 2 == 0) return mid * mid;
    else return mid * mid * x;
  }

  Num ackermann_bignum(Num m, Num n) {
    if (m <= 1) return n + (m + 1);
    else if (m == 2) return Num(2) * n + 3;
    else if (m == 3) return bignum_pow(2, n + 3) - 3;
    else {
      cout << "Don't put m >= 4\n";
      exit(1);
    } 
  }
}

Num dummy = 0;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  int test_type = 0;
  if (argc > 1) {
    try {
      test_type = std::stoi(string(argv[1]));
    } catch (...) {
      test_type = 0;
    }
  }
  int lim = (test_type == 0) ? 63 : 17;

  MyTimer timer;
  timer.startCounter();
    
  for (int m = 0; m <= 3; m++)
  for (int n = 0; n <= lim; n++) {
    if (test_type == 0) {
      dummy = ackermann_bignum(m, n);      
    } else if (test_type == 1) {
      dummy = ackermann_bignum_smallres(m, n);
    } else {
      dummy = ackermann(m, n);      
    }
    cout << "ackermann(" << m << ", " << n << ") = " << dummy << "\n";    
  }

  cout << "ackermann cost = " << timer.getCounterMsPrecise() << "\n";
}
```

Compile the above using `g++ ackermann.cpp -shared -fPIC -O3 -std=c++17 -o ackermann.so`

To run separately, use

```
g++ -o main_cpp ackermann.cpp -O3 -std=c++17
./main_cpp
```

Then in the same folder, run this script (modified from @Stefan Pochmann answer)

```
def A_Stefan_row_class(m, n):
    class A0:
        def __getitem__(self, n):
            return n + 1
    class A:
        def __init__(self, a):
            self.a = a
            self.n = 0
            self.value = a[1]
        def __getitem__(self, n):
            while self.n < n:
                self.value = self.a[self.value]
                self.n += 1
            return self.value
    a = A0()
    for _ in range(m):
        a = A(a)
    return a[n]


from collections import defaultdict

def A_Stefan_row_lists(m, n):
    memo = defaultdict(list)
    def a(m, n):
        if not m:
            return n + 1
        if m not in memo:
            memo[m] = [a(m-1, 1)]
        Am = memo[m]
        while len(Am) <= n:
            Am.append(a(m-1, Am[-1]))
        return Am[n]
    return a(m, n)


from itertools import count

def A_Stefan_generators(m, n):
    a = count(1)
    def up(a, x=1):
        for i, ai in enumerate(a):
            if i == x:
                x = ai
                yield x
    for _ in range(m):
        a = up(a)
    return next(up(a, n))


def A_Stefan_paper(m, n):
    next = [0] * (m + 1)
    goal = [1] * m + [-1]
    while True:
        value = next[0] + 1
        transferring = True
        i = 0
        while transferring:
            if next[i] == goal[i]:
                goal[i] = value
            else:
                transferring = False
            next[i] += 1
            i += 1
        if next[m] == n + 1:
            return value


def A_Stefan_generators_2(m, n):
    def a0():
        n = yield
        while True:
            n = yield n + 1
    def up(a):
        next(a)
        a = a.send
        i, x = -1, 1
        n = yield
        while True:
            while i < n:
                x = a(x)
                i += 1
            n = yield x
    a = a0()
    for _ in range(m):
        a = up(a)
    next(a)
    return a.send(n)


def A_Stefan_m_recursion(m, n):
    ix = [None] + [(-1, 1)] * m
    def a(m, n):
        if not m:
            return n + 1
        i, x = ix[m]
        while i < n:
            x = a(m-1, x)
            i += 1
        ix[m] = i, x
        return x
    return a(m, n)


def A_Stefan_function_stack(m, n):
    def a(n):
        return n + 1
    for _ in range(m):
        def a(n, a=a, ix=[-1, 1]):
            i, x = ix
            while i < n:
                x = a(x)
                i += 1
            ix[:] = i, x
            return x
    return a(n)


from itertools import count, islice

def A_Stefan_generator_stack(m, n):
    a = count(1)
    for _ in range(m):
        a = (
            x
            for a, x in [(a, 1)]
            for i, ai in enumerate(a)
            if i == x
            for x in [ai]
        )
    return next(islice(a, n, None))


from itertools import count, islice

def A_Stefan_generator_stack2(m, n):
    a = count(1)
    def up(a):
        i, x = 0, 1
        while True:
            i, x = x+1, next(islice(a, x-i, None))
            yield x
    for _ in range(m):
        a = up(a)
    return next(islice(a, n, None))


def A_Stefan_generator_stack3(m, n):
    def a(m):
        if not m:
            yield from count(1)
        x = 1
        for i, ai in enumerate(a(m-1)):
            if i == x:
                x = ai
                yield x
    return next(islice(a(m), n, None))


def A_Stefan_generator_stack4(m, n):
    def a(m):
        if not m:
            return count(1)
        return (
            x
            for x in [1]
            for i, ai in enumerate(a(m-1))
            if i == x
            for x in [ai]
        )
    return next(islice(a(m), n, None))


def A_templatetypedef(i, n):
    positions = [-1] * (i + 1)
    values = [0] + [1] * i
    
    while positions[i] != n:       
        values[0]    += 1
        positions[0] += 1
            
        j = 1
        while j <= i and positions[j - 1] == values[j]:
            values[j] = values[j - 1]
            positions[j] += 1
            j += 1

    return values[i]

import ctypes
mylib = ctypes.CDLL('./ackermann.so')
mylib.ackermann.argtypes = [ctypes.c_int64, ctypes.c_int64]
mylib.ackermann.restype = ctypes.c_int64

def c_ackermann(m, n):
    return mylib.ackermann(m,n)

funcs = [
    c_ackermann,
    A_Stefan_row_class,
    A_Stefan_row_lists,
    A_Stefan_generators,
    A_Stefan_paper,
    A_Stefan_generators_2,
    A_Stefan_m_recursion,
    A_Stefan_function_stack,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack2,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack3,
    A_Stefan_generator_stack4,
    A_templatetypedef
]

N = 18
args = (
    [(0, n) for n in range(N)] +
    [(1, n) for n in range(N)] +
    [(2, n) for n in range(N)] +
    [(3, n) for n in range(N)]
)

from time import time

def print(*args, print=print, file=open('out.txt', 'w')):
    print(*args)
    print(*args, file=file, flush=True)
    
expect = none = object()
for _ in range(3):
  for f in funcs:
    t = time()
    result = [f(m, n) for m, n in args]
    # print(f'{(time()-t) * 1e3 :5.1f} ms ', f.__name__)
    print(f'{(time()-t) * 1e3 :5.0f} ms ', f.__name__)
    if expect is none:
        expect = result
    elif result != expect:
        raise Exception(f'{f.__name__} failed')
    del result
  print()

  c_ackermann(-1, -1)
```

Output:

```
   32 ms  c_ackermann
 1897 ms  A_Stefan_row_class
 1427 ms  A_Stefan_row_lists
  437 ms  A_Stefan_generators
 1366 ms  A_Stefan_paper
  479 ms  A_Stefan_generators_2
  801 ms  A_Stefan_m_recursion
  725 ms  A_Stefan_function_stack
  716 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack
 1113 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack2
  551 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack3
  682 ms  A_Stefan_generator_stack4
 1622 ms  A_templatetypedef
```

Comment: This solution is incorrect for `mylib.ackermann(3, 63)` (and many others). It should return 9223372036854775808, but it returns some architecture-specific incorrect value, such as 1 on amd64. This is because this value doesn't fit in an int64_t.

Comment: Python integers are arbitrary precision.  Use https://gmplib.org/ or something similar to support larger integers if you want to be comparable.  Otherwise, sure, it's very easy to be much faster than Python when your integers fit in 64-bit.  (CPython uses 30-bit chunks even on 64-bit machines.)

Comment: Oh, I thought Python uses `int64_t` by default. And since the top answer also only measure small value, I didn't use any BigNum library. I'll update the answer

Comment: I just added 2 extra answers using bignum, which should cover all possible cases. I don't bother with `m >= 4`  because the number is too big anyway.

Comment: If you don't bother with output values which don't fit in RAM, then you don't even need a full bignum library with multiplication and exponentiation. You can just generate the output bits directly in a char* or int* array. Most of them will be 1 anyway. The algorithm will be similar to my.Python fuction, just faster.

Comment: btw `ackermann(3,63) == 73786976294838206461`, not `9223372036854775808`. I used wolfram alpha

Comment: This is incorrect solution